# SQL query with 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need some assistance with an SQL query. The relational view is below:

[image: relational tables]

The output should show **Project Name**, **Project Manager Username**, and **Project Due Date**. The difficulty is that the above output must be shown for which a specific worker who is assigned to a task *inside* of that project. So for example, Task 'B.1' is added to Project 'B', a worker is assigned to Task 'B.1' would see the above output for Project 'B'.

Hope this makes sense.

EDIT: I need the ProjectID and WorkerID as well to pass the ID and for a Where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
select project.projectid, project.name, managers.username, project.duedate, task.workerid from project 
inner join task on project.projectid = task.projectid
inner join user as managers on project.projectmanagerid = managers.userid
inner join user as workers on task.workerid = workers.userid
```

Comment: Seems to work, but when I add project.ProjectID to the query (which I need to pass to the next page) I get an error. What am I doing wrong? I just need ProjectID as well.

Comment: I've edited my answer. you should not get errors unless you have some typos

Comment: Sorry I've forgotten that I need to select the WorkerID as well, in order to make a where clause for the user logged in. How will this change the query?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, this is another way to do it, it should be something like this :

`SELECT Project.Name, User.FirstName, Project.DueDate 
FROM Project, User, Task
WHEN User.ProjectManagerID = User.UserID
AND Project.ProjectID = Task.Project ID`

I think that's all.

- The first line you choose what you want.
- The second, you select all the (necessary) tables
- The third, you need to make the relation between the ID of the ProjectManager and the ID of the User, to select the firstname of the Manager.
- Finally, the last line is present to make the link between the task of the project and the project.

Comment: Please do not do joins in this manner. It is a nightmare to maintain.